# NLP in Python3 - count up occurrences of specific terms in a large string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, nlp

I have numerous files, containing pages of text.  While looping through each file, I would like to extract counts for terms that I'm specifically interested in.

For example, I have something like the below (simplified example - actual is 2-5 pages of text):

```
to_process = 'soccer football soccer asdlkj assdasda asdsasad  football soccer'
print(to_process)
```

And I would like to count up number of times 'soccer' and 'football' appear in the text:

```
dict_of_counts = {'soccer':0,'football':0}
print(dict_of_counts)
```

With expected output being:

```
expected_output = {'soccer':3,'football':2}
```

Could anyone provide me with some clues on how I would go above solving this issue, in the most efficient manner possible (I have thousands of papers, and hundreds of terms I'd be looking for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your code to handle capitalization and punctuation, I would suggest using the [flashtext](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext) package:

```
to_process = 'Soccer, football soccer, asdlkj assdasda asdsasad  football; soccer.'
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
kp = KeywordProcessor()
words_to_look_for = ['soccer', 'football']
for a in words_to_look_for:
    kp.add_keyword(a)
foundList = kp.extract_keywords(to_process)
dict_of_counts = {}
for a in foundList:
    dict_of_counts[a] = dict_of_counts.get(a, 0) +1
print(dict_of_counts)
#{'soccer': 3, 'football': 2}
```

Comment: thank you for thinking ahead for me regarding punctuation / capitalization.  I did go ahead and convert all the text to lowercase, but this package does seem to handle punctuation well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dict comprehension (using `collections.Counter` and `re.sub`):

```
import re
from collections import Counter

to_process = '>>SocceR... !football! soccer *asdlkj assdasda? asdsasad ; FOOtball;  soCCer'

words = ['soccer', 'football']

all_counts = Counter(re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', to_process).lower().split())

dict_of_counts = {w : all_counts[w] for w in words}

print(dict_of_counts)
```

Output:

```
{'soccer': 3, 'football': 2}
```

Comment: thank you for response!  this works well as long as there's not punctuation involved.

Comment: @FlyingZebra1 To handle such cases, use NLTK (I just edited my answer to show how to use it).

Comment: thank you.  NLTK is definitely a package i've heard of before, But will need to research why its still not picking up messy punctuation such as   soccer..   (note the two periods)

Comment: @FlyingZebra1 In this case you don't need any third-party libraries, just use Python's `re` and `collections` modules (check the edit).